# What does sx={{'& > :not(style)': {m1}}} do in MUI 5?

Tags: css, material-ui

I see them use this on their TextField page for having TextFields align correctly as the page gets smaller. What exactly does this css do?

`sx={{'& > :not(style)': {m1}}}`

Comment: I'm guessing that `sx` is a breakpoint like tailwind has `sm:`? `&` usually is referencing *this* element, so this is selecting all children of this element that are not style elements, giving them a style of whatever `m1` is.

Comment: `sx` just allows you to inject `css` inline for that component and its sub components in `Mui 5`. If you want the answer you gave was correct if you want to make that an answer for the question. I did apply the margin of 1 to all children of that component.